# Getting a `badOrigin` on Scheduler pallet

Tags: pallet

I have successfully added the scheduler pallet but in polkadot.js frontend I am getting a `badOrigin`:

[image]

What could be the issue?

Comment: can you try with a non-root account? Bob or charlie. You can also check doc here
https://docs.rs/pallet-scheduler/3.0.0/src/pallet_scheduler/lib.rs.html#31-34

Comment: What does your config look like? What do you have set as the `ScheduleOrigin`: https://docs.rs/pallet-scheduler/latest/pallet_scheduler/trait.Config.html#associatedtype.ScheduleOrigin

Answer (score 1):

Try this: In PolkadotJs, **Go to Developer -> Sudo -> scheduler** ( Instance Pallet) -> schedule(extrinsic)

If you configure like this https://github.com/PureStake/moonbeam/blob/master/runtime/moonbeam/src/lib.rs#L471